# What is the difference between Google Service Framework(GSF)&Google Mobile Service(GMS)?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am learning Google Cloud Message recently, it requires both GSF and GMS(which new name is Google Play Service, but not that Google Play app).
I decompile the code of both, but I don't know the usage of them, and don't know why Google provider these two services, why not one? And what's the difference of them?

Answer (score 3):

I think it would be good to define them first:

-[Google Mobile Services](https://www.android.com/gms/) (GMS) is a collection of Google applications and APIs that help support functionality across devices. [Samples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_mobile_services) are Gmail, Chrome, Google+, Google Maps and Youtube.

-[Google Play Services(Google Service Freamwork)](https://www.quora.com/What-does-Google-Service-Framework-do-What-gets-affected-if-a-phone-tablet-does-not-have-it-installed-Can-the-user-install-it-on-the-phone-tablet-without-having-to-root-it#) is used to make sure that everything is running smoothly on your device.

It takes care of the following:

1.Google Backup

2.Play Store Services

3.Contacts Sync

4.Account Manager